# Out of memory exception when dowloading file (DevExpress Filemanager)

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I am using DevExpress and on the server side I have the following:

```
var fileStreamResult = FileManagerExtension.DownloadFiles(settings, provider, FileManagerFileDownloadingEventHandler);
```

Where the provider is an AzureProvider. The settings are:

```
settings.SettingsEditing.AllowDownload = true;
settings.Settings.AllowedFileExtensions = new[] {".avi", ".mov"};
```

Now if I download a file that is ~30 MB, it works fine but when I try it with a file that is 200 MB, then `.DownloadFiles` returns null.

Also when I look at the first chance exceptions I see:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
```

I don't know what the problem is but I have also set the following in my config file:

```
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="30000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
```

I played with the above value adding extra zeros but, still no luck.

Anyone has any ideas? thanks.

Edit: please note that the upload of 200MB is fine. The problem occurs during downloading

Comment: Refer this link will help you https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T508638/aspxfilemanager-what-is-the-limit-of-the-file-size-that-can-be-uploaded-and-how-to

Comment: Thanks @niks, but my issue is downloading. Uploading of the 200 MB is fine.

Comment: The exception can mean one of two things: When the MemoryStream tries to allocate memory (i assume it wants to allocate as much memory as the file size, in this case 200MB), either there is not enough free memory, or the large object heap is too fragmented and the runtime is unable to find a continuous free memory space of the required size. It's up to you to figure out what exactly the reason is: Profile your program, watch the memory consumption of your program in the Task Manager, try to defrag/compact the large object heap before attempting to download, etc...

Comment: @elgonzo, thanks for the suggestion. I tried GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce, and then did a collect and got the same result. Memory-wise I have 32GB RAM.

Comment: How much RAM you have installed is not relevant at all. How much of that RAM is free/available matters...

Comment: @elgonzo, nearly 20GB free. The VS Diagnostic panel, shows the process memory rising from 420mb to 534MB then stable at the level, until I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DevExpress support, they highlighted it was because IIS Express runs out of memory, as it is possibly being run as a 32-bit process. So changing Visual Studio to use the 64-bit did the trick. Hopefully this helps someone in the future:

[How to change Visual Studio option to use the 64-bit version of IIS Express](https://ppolyzos.com/2015/12/01/enable-x64-bit-version-of-iis-express/)